Text Element finding issue
1–10 of 137 from this xpath i have to copy the value 1–10 of 137 and this is dynamic after every record it will be update how can i ?
i tried all the method but didnt gettng solution below is the one method but not getting id in print
element = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//p[@class = 'MuiTablePagination-displayedRows css-1ohtvq8']")
text_content = element.text

# Copy text to clipboard
pyperclip.copy(text_content)

print(text_content)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
